# Sending multiple headers with Swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I'm trying to setup Swagger >=2.0 but i'm not able to send many headers with single request. That's my index.html js code:

```
$(function () {
  var url = window.location.search.match(/url=([^&]+)/);
  if (url && url.length > 1) {
    url = decodeURIComponent(url[1]);
  } else {
    url = "http://localhost:9033/api/swagger.json";
  }
  window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
    url: url,
    dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
    supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch'],
    onComplete: function(swaggerApi, swaggerUi){
      if(typeof initOAuth == "function") {
        initOAuth({
          clientId: "your-client-id",
          realm: "your-realms",
          appName: "your-app-name"
        });
      }

      $('pre code').each(function(i, e) {
        hljs.highlightBlock(e)
      });

      addApiKeyAuthorization();
    },
    onFailure: function(data) {
      log("Unable to Load SwaggerUI");
    },
    docExpansion: "none",
    apisSorter: "alpha",
    showRequestHeaders: true
  });

  function addApiKeyAuthorization(){
    var key = encodeURIComponent($('#input_apiKey')[0].value);
    if(key && key.trim() != "") {
        window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("X-My-Header", new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("X-My-Header", "test value", "header"));
        window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("Authorization", new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("Authorization", key, "header"));
        log("added key " + key);
    }
  }

  $('#input_apiKey').change(addApiKeyAuthorization);

  // if you have an apiKey you would like to pre-populate on the page for demonstration purposes...
  /*
    var apiKey = "myApiKeyXXXX123456789";
    $('#input_apiKey').val(apiKey);
  */

  window.swaggerUi.load();

  function log() {
    if ('console' in window) {
      console.log.apply(console, arguments);
    }
  }
```

As you can see i added two headers, but only the first one is sent with request. If i reverse them, then the other one will be sent, but i never manage to send both. Documentation is pretty straightforward and says:

> Note! You can pass **multiple** header params on a single request, just use unique names for them (key is used in the above example).

To be clear, both headers are added to Access-Control-Allow-Headers, and both can be recived separatelly by server, the case is that i'm not able to send them together.

The question:
Does anyone know how to handle that?

(There is also on important assumption, these headers ale global for all my api's, so i would like to put them directly in swagger ui instead of documenting every api method).

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug. Quick fix is described here:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1374

Issue can be closed.